# Containers should read directly from state or from ownProps whenever possible?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Suppose the following application state:

```
{ todos: [{ id: 1, text: 'Foo'}] }
```

What is the preferred (or the best, if I may) way to populate presentational components from containers: reading directly from state or reading from `ownProps` whenever possible? Why?

Example reading from ownProps:

```
TodoItem from '../components/TodoItem';
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { data: ownProps.data };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return { onComplete: () => {} }
};
const TodoItemContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem);

class TodoList extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return this.props.items.map(item => {
      return <TodoItemContainer index={item.id} data={item} />;
    });
  }
}
```

Example reading directly from state:

```
import TodoItem from '../components/TodoItem';
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { data: state.todos[ownProps.id] };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return { onComplete: () => {} }
};
const TodoItemContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoItem);

class TodoList extends Component {
  // ...
  render() {
    return this.props.items.map(item => {
      return <TodoItemContainer index={item.id} id={item.id} />;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid.  The second approach is particularly useful if you're working with normalized data, and can also be an improvement to performance.

See these links for more information:

- [Redux FAQ: how do I organize nested data?](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-nested-data)
- [Redux docs: Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html)
- [Slides: High Performance Redux](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/)

Comment: Although useful, I think your answer might be a little bit incorrect. This answer is the one I particularly found more correct https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/570#issuecomment-266764603.